# Problems in use mongodb and visual studio

Tags: c++, mongodb, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use mongodb in visual studio and I am following this steps tutorial:

[How I installed the Windows 7 64x C++ driver/mongoDB to work with Visual Studio 2010](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/128tmfjfdj/how-i-installed-the-windows-7-64x-c-driver-mongodb-to-work-with-visual-studio-2010)

But I receive the following error message:

> Error: cannot open the source file: "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

Does anybody knows why I have this error?

Comment: I would start by tracking down the path of that file. I mean in whatever folder you added to your Additional Include Directories does the folder `mongo/client` exist?

Comment: I checked and yes, the client folder is there.

Comment: This is my mongo folder paths: C:\mongodb\src\mongo C:\mongodb\lib

Comment: Did you add `C:\mongodb\src\mongo` to the Additional Include Directories of Visual Studio? If so is there a folder `C:\mongodb\src\mongo\mongo\client` or is there a folder `C:\mongodb\src\mongo\client`? If the latter you needed to add `C:\mongodb\src\` to your Additional Include Directories.

Comment: This my configuration: Configuration Properties->vc++ Directories->Include Directories
C:\mongodb

Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
C:\mongodb\src

Comment: ***This my configuration: Configuration Properties->vc++ Directories->Include Directories C:\mongodb Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories C:\mongodb\src*** Both look wrong to me from the information you provided. I would expect `Configuration Properties->vc++ Directories->Include Directories C:\mongodb\src` and `Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories C:\mongodb\lib`

Comment: Please show the SCons invocation you used to build the driver.

Comment: @user3619911 I can't help you unless you provide the SCons invocation. Or, if you have solved your problem, please post an answer.